# Summing values based on date

Tags: excel-2010

Spreadsheet has 2 columns. Column A contains a date. Column B contains a numeric value.  How do I sum numeric values in column B that match a specific year in column A. I tried

```
=sum((year(A1:A5)=2016)*B1:B5)
```

and

```
=vlookup(year(a1:a5)=2015,1,false)
```

Neither work... can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

For **2016**:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(A1:A10)=2016)*(B1:B10))
```

with data like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance.  Your answer worked for me!

Comment: David, I would now like to expand on your above answer to sum values matching a date from multiple worksheets...I modified your example as follows =sumproduct(--year(A1:A10)=2016)*('Worksheet1'!B1:B10,'Worksheet2'!B1:B10,'Worksheet3'!B1:B10...)) but I'm getting a #Value error.  Any assistance would be appreciated.